# Hiding a DisplayFor element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

Hello I have a 'td' that looks like this

```
 <td style="font-weight:bold">
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "qtyInItem" } })
 </td>
```

And Jquery code that makes a clone of my row that looks like this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                //getting closest tr
                var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    // remove cloned row
                    $('#' + Id + 'clone').remove();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".qtyInItem").hide();
                    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");
                }

            });
        });
```

But it is not hiding my displayFor for the cloned row.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Solved by just placing the td in a span then I am able to hide the span

```
<span class="qtyInItem"> @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
</span>
```

then I'm able to hide the span by doing

```
$clone.find('.qtyInItem').hide();
```